# async function equivalent of a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have a function that returns a `promise` like this:

```
let aFunction= function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject){
       someNodeApi(params, function(err, data)) {
          if(err) {
            return reject(err);
          }
          if(data meets certain criteria) {
             someOtherNodeApi(params, function(err, data)) {
                // handle conditions.
             }
          }
          resolve(data);
       }         
    })
}
```

I want to have an `async` function equivalent for this kind of function. In short, I need something like this:

```
let aFunction = async function(){
   someNodeApi(params, function(err, data){
      if(err) {
          // reject condition
      }
      // resolve condition.
   })
}
```

So what should be in above `reject` and `resolve` conditions so that all the places where I call the function like this:

```
aFunction()
  .then(data=>{})
  .catch(err=>{})
```

It should be unchanged.

**EDIT**

I have to clarify that my question is not about *how to call the async function*. But its about how to convert a function that returns a Promise to be able to use the goodness of async-await pattern without having to modify the way its called. (A very common scenario when you are dealing with pre async-await era node js code).

Comment: Your premise is wrong. An async function is called differently (`var result = await foo()`). If you want to keep the  `then catch` pattern, you need to keep using a Promise. Which brings me to the important question: *why* do you want to move away from promises?

Comment: @ChrisG I want to move away from promises for the same reason as to why async-await was added to node js. Which is that its a better way and more like synchronous programming.

Comment: After your edit, it seems like your question is either. How do I promisify an api, or how do I use async/await. If the first, use a library. If the second, read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @MattWay essentially an async function returns a Promise. So using async/await in a certain way becomes a matter of choice and opinion. So I don't think my question is about how do I use it.

Comment: If your question is `how to convert a function that returns a Promise to be able to use the goodness of async-await pattern without having to modify the way its called` then as far as I know, the answer is "you can't". Plus, as far as I can gather from your comments, you indeed *are* asking how to use async / await because if you knew, this question wouldn't exist. `essentially an async function returns a Promise` No, it doesn't.

Comment: @ChrisG check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function for the return value. and it clearly says `A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within the async function.`

Comment: @rahulserver That page explicitly states that the return value is an [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction) The code on the example page also doesn't return anything from the async function. Doesn't matter anyway, because `.then()` is part of the Promise pattern, so your entire questions is nonsensical from the get-go.

Comment: @ChrisG https://i.imgur.com/qwYKjJG.png (Scroll down a bit)

Comment: Experimenting with this, it turns out that one can indeed call `then()` on the return value of an async function, and that MDN apparently mistakenly uses "returns" instead of "creates" in its first paragraph on the linked page... which doesn't make this question any less nonsensical though, since *if* the point is to use "synchronous" code, why would one want to keep `then()` callback constructs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I like to write **async/await** , makes it pretty straightforward. All of the code inside can be read as sync.
***EDIT***: await will work only if the API returns a promise object that is either resolved or rejected. **await** does not resolve promises.

```
function someAPI() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      someNodeApi(params, function(err, data){
            if(err) {
                reject(error)
            } else {
              resolve(data)
            }
            // resolve condition.
        })
    });
  }


async function aFunction() {
  try {
    const result = await someAPI();
    return result;
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
}

aFunction()
.then((res) => console.log(res))
```

Comment: I think this is a great answer! This does answer my queries. In short we must use await everywhere inside an async function.

Comment: This won't work, as @rahulserver's api is not promisified yet.

Comment: @MattWay you are right. But I can use utils.promisify to do that conversion. Conceptually this answer addresses my query. However it would be worth editing the answer to include that the function needs to be promisified

Comment: @rahulserver If you use a promisifying library, then this answer is totally redundant. As I said in my answer, you don't need aFunction at all.

Comment: Yes, your API needs to return a promise, I will edit to show you.

Comment: @MattWay aFunction is supposed to have several api calls that are chained and depend on conditions. I will edit my question to further elaborate. So I don't think its redundant.

Answer (score 1):

When changing to async/await, what changes isn't your promise setup, but rather how you make calls to your promises. For example:

```
aFunction()
  .then(data=>{})
  .catch(err=>{})

// becomes
try{
  const data = await aFunction()
}catch(err){
  // do something with err
}
```

Just bear in mind that the function that *uses* await needs to be set to `async`.

---

If your `someNodeApi` call was already setup for promises, then the result would still be exactly the same, you simply wouldn't need `aFunction` at all. For example, if you used a promisifying library on your api, then you don't need `aFunction` at all.

```
someNodeApi(params)
  .then(data => {})
  .catch(err => {})

// or

const data = await someNodeApi(params)
if(data meets certain criteria) {
   const otherData = someOtherNodeApi(params)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt. Certainly looks good. But then what would you do in cases when you are going to use a lot of api calls(callback based) inside that async function? I mean i just want to make the code inside the function more like synchronous. In short If node syntax allowed it, i would just use await keyword inside my promise based functions without async.

Answer (score 1):

> Snippet1 : Here, you can see the usage of async-await

```js
let fn = async function(a) {
 let val = 10;
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(a > val) {
   resolve("+++++Resolved");
  }
  else {
   reject("++++++Rejected")
  }
 })
};

(async () => {
 try {
  let result1 = await fn(20);
  console.log(result1);

  let result2 = await fn(5);
  console.log(result2);
 }
 catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
 }
    
})();
```

> Snippet2 : Here you can see that using .then.catch will not harm or break any of your code.

```js
let fn = async function(a) {
 let val = 10;
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(a > val) {
   resolve("+++++Resolved");
  }
  else {
   reject("++++++Rejected")
  }
 })
};

fn(20).then(response => {
 console.log(response);
});

fn(5)
 .then(response => {
  console.log(response);
 })
 .catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
 })
```

It does not break your code if you use fn().then.catch pattern on a Promise returning async fumction.
However, using await makes it more elegant.

> Feel free to refer a detailed article that I have written on basics of
>   async-await and why async-await compared to .then.catch pattern, pros
>   and cons here: https://github.com/cskru/asyncAwaitSimplified

I have included code snippets which you can directly copy paste and try out.

PS: I have used async IIFE in the above snippets.
This is because awaits can be made inside async function/context only.

I'd also recommend you to check this [article](http://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html) to get a solid foundation wrt async-await.

Happy learning!

Cheers,
Kruthika